# Using a class name in jQuery's .closest()

Tags: jquery, class, math, closest

I'm attempting to do some calculations for a "running total", this is my code:

```
$('.quantity_input').live('change',function(){         
                var ValOne = parseFloat($(this).val());
                var ValTwo = parseFloat($(".price").text())
                var totalTotal = ((ValOne) * (ValTwo));                         
                $('.cost_of_items').closest('.cost_of_items').text(totalTotal.toFixed(2));
                calcTotal();
            });
```

.quantity_input is an input, .price is the price of the product, .cost_of_items is where i want to update the total cost for the item, ie. item1 = £5 x 3 quantity = £15 total for item1
calcTotal() is a function that just updates a total cost for the order. The problem is keeping all the math in one row of the table, ie i'm doing the calc in the code above and its not sticking to its row, its updating all the fields with class .cost_of_items etc...

the problem with showing my html is that its dynamically added by jQuery .appends() but here is the relevant jQuery:

```
$('#items').append('<tr class="tableRow"><td><a class="removeItem" href="#"><img src="/admin/images/delete.png"></img></a><td class="om_part_no">' + omPartNo + '</td><td>' + supPartNo + '</td><td>' + cat + '</td><td class="description">' + desc + '</td><td>' + manuf + '</td><td>' + list + '</td><td>' + disc + '</td><td><p class="add_edit">Add/Edit</p><input type="text" class="quantity_input" name="quantity_input" /></td><td class="price_each_nett price">' + priceEach + '</td><td class="cost_of_items"></td><td><p class="add_edit">Add/Edit</p><input type="text" class="project_ref_input" name="project_ref_input" /><p class="project_ref"></p></td></tr>');
```

EDIT:

Working solution:

```
$('.quantity_input').live('change',function(){         
                var ValOne = parseFloat($(this).val());
                var ValTwo = parseFloat($(this).closest('tr').find('.price').text())
                var totalTotal = ((ValOne) * (ValTwo));                         
                $(this).closest('tr').find('.cost_of_items').text(totalTotal.toFixed(2));
                calcTotal();
            });
```

Comment: The line here that looks wrong is `$('.cost_of_items').closest('.cost_of_items')`.  Could you show us your HTML as well?

Comment: All the parentheses in ((ValOne) * (ValTwo)) do absolutely nothing.

Comment: @user - You're missing a closing `</td>` tag in your `.append()`.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You need to find the `.cost_of_items` in the `<tr>` containing `this`:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('.cost_of_items')
```

Answer (score 8):

Closest will find the closest ancestor (parent, grandparent), but you will then need to do a find in order to find the correct element to update. For example, if you have an element in a table row and you need another element in that same row:

```
$('.myElement').closest('tr').find('.someOtherElement');
```

Edit:

In your case, you will want

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('.cost_of_items').text(totalTotal.toFixed(2));
```

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't use `.find()`. I'm guessing it will probably be a bit more efficient to traverse up to the closest `<td>` and get the sibling `<td>` with the `.cost_of_items` class using [jQuery's `.siblings()` method](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).

```
$(this).closest('td').siblings('.cost_of_items');
```

---

**EDIT:** To clarify, here's the markup from the `.append()`:

```
<tr class="tableRow">
     <!-- NOTE THAT THE CLOSING </td> IS MISSING FOR THE FIRST <td> -->
    <td><a class="removeItem" href="#"><img src="/admin/images/delete.png"></img></a>
    <td class="om_part_no">' + omPartNo + '</td>
    <td>' + supPartNo + '</td>
    <td>' + cat + '</td>
    <td class="description">' + desc + '</td>
    <td>' + manuf + '</td>
    <td>' + list + '</td>
    <td>' + disc + '</td>
     <!-- TRAVERSE TO HERE -->
    <td>
       <p class="add_edit">Add/Edit</p>
        <!-- START HERE -->
       <input type="text" class="quantity_input" name="quantity_input" />
    </td>
    <td class="price_each_nett price">' + priceEach + '</td>
     <!-- SIBLING IS HERE -->
    <td class="cost_of_items"></td>
    <td><p class="add_edit">Add/Edit</p><input type="text" class="project_ref_input" name="project_ref_input" /><p class="project_ref"></p></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: cost_of_items isn't a sibling - it is a descendant of a sibling.

Comment: @Keith - Thanks for the down-vote, but you're wrong. `<td class="cost_of_items"></td>`.

Comment: Sorry - I read it quick and thought it was tr. I'll undo my vote

Answer (score -2):

You don't need to use find. [`closest` takes a context argument](http://api.jquery.com/closest/). that helps you narrow down the field of search. You should use that.

Comment: The context parameter just makes it so that the result returned must be within the context of a specific ancestor. Because thee `.cost_of_items` is not an ancestor of `.quantity_input`, some other method is still needed, like `.find()`.

Comment: Yes downvote me because the asker's code is so problematic that he has to use a find() with a call to closest in an event instead of having the context readily available.

Comment: Not sure if you're referring to me, but if so, I didn't down-vote you. I just pointed out the mistake.

Comment: @user - Your code is fine. You have a starting point at the element that received the event and need to get the proper `.cost_of_items` element relative to that starting point. Nothing wrong with traversing over to it.

Comment: General comment to whoever downvoted what I think is an ok answer. I guess I should have stipulated that you should probably have the context already available based on how the event is bound.

Comment: I think you're mis-understanding how either `.closest()` or its context parameter works. The `.closest()` method *only* looks at ancestors. Because the targeted element is not an ancestor of `this`, `.closest()` will not find it. All the context does is limit the ancestors to those within the context.