# Find closest table row element with a particular class attribute looking in reverse from current element

Tags: jquery, class, html-table, reverse, closest

I have a JqGrid and want to toggle automatically the display of the last edited row/group when returning to the view/page containing the grid.

The process I have is

1. Write the last edited OrderId to a session variable on completion of add/edit
2. Pass this to the view where is is held in a hidden form element

What I would like to do now is use this "id" to locate the nearest (in reverse) grouping table row which I can then use to toggle the display.

The  for the OrderId is easily identified since the id"" attribute matches the OrderId.

The grouping  element though is 0 indexed and numbered only according to it's position in the grid i.e. it does not relate to the OrderId or OrderLinkId.

**24/10/2012** Amended the below example to demonstrate that the group header  elements are closed before the individual Order  elements ie. siblings not parent/child

```
<tr id="clientOrderGridghead_0_6" class="ui-widget-content jqgroup ui-row-ltr clientOrderGridghead_0" role="row">
.....Group Header 6 Content.....
</tr>
<tr id="403" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr" style="" tabindex="-1" role="row">
</tr>
<tr id="414" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr" style="" tabindex="-1" role="row">
</tr>
<tr id="418" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr" style="" tabindex="-1" role="row">
</tr>
<tr id="clientOrderGridghead_0_7" class="ui-widget-content jqgroup ui-row-ltr clientOrderGridghead_0" role="row">
......Group Header 7 Content......
</tr>
```

The example above shows the top  element which acts as the group header, with the subsequent 3  elements being the record rows for the related Orders.

The header  element always has the class

```
class="ui-widget-content jqgroup ui-row-ltr clientOrderGridghead_0"
```

I have been able to successfully do the toggling by hard coding the id of the group  element as follows

```
jQuery('#clientOrderGrid').jqGrid('groupingToggle','clientOrderGridghead_0_6');
```

But am now struggling to get the id necessary to plug in to the groupingToggle call and make it dynamic.

I've tried the following

```
var groupId = $('#' + lastOrderId).closest('tr').find('.ui-widget-content jqgroup ui-row-ltr clientOrderGridghead_0').attr('id');
```

After seeing the example here
[Using a class name in jQuery's .closest()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096950/using-a-class-name-in-jquerys-closest)

But but this returns undefined.

Any pointers greatly appreciated.

**24/10/2012**
Another attempt

```
var groupId = $('#' + lastOrderId).closest('tbody').find('.ui-widget-content jqgroup ui-row-ltr clientOrderGridghead_0').attr('id');
```

But still no joy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should go for

```
var groupId = $('#' + lastOrderId).parent().find('.clientOrderGridghead_0').attr('id');
```

EDIT: Removed unnecessary classes in find.

EDIT 2: I couldn't understand your question at the first place.

Please try this:

```
var groupId = $('#' + lastOrderId).prev('.clientOrderGridghead_0').attr('id');
```

I seriously hope this works for you this time.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Pulkit Mittal however this still returns 'undefined'. Though it's not clear from my original post the group header is closed before - and does not enclose - the other <tr> elements, so I believe they are regarded as siblings rather then parent/child.

Comment: My mistake I think what @Pulkit Mittal suggested is equivalent to my last attempt as the <tbody> is the first parent node when traversing back up the DOM tree.

Comment: Thanks @Pulkit I tested your last edited suggestion and am now getting the id attribute back. Only problem is that since the all <tr> elements are enclosed on the one parent <tbody> I always get the id of the same group header <tr> element returned i.e. clientOrderGridghead_0_0, the first in the sequence. I have edited my original attempt to use the 'closest' method with find, but am now back to getting 'undefined'

Comment: Hey bro, check out my update this time. I couldn't get your question until before your last comment. I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Puklit, no problem, my question wasn't the best in the first place. I'm away from work just now, but will test first thing tomorrow and get back to you. Thanks again,

Comment: Just a note, this relates to JqGrid. I ran into an anomaly when the header to be toggled is the first on the grid. I watched and found that when this is the case 'undefined' is returned. I put an if statement i to default to first row if this happened i.e. (groupId == null) : 'clientOrderGridghead_0_0' : groupId